# How to choose the overloaded function called

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I am a beginner in C++, and I want to change the function version which will be called in this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class C1 {};

class C2 : public C1 {};

void func(C1 var) {
    std::cout << "Func 1" << std::endl;
}

void func(C2 var) {
    std::cout << "Func 2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    C1 *teste1 = new C1;
    C1 *teste2 = new C2;

    func(*teste1);                 // Want "Func 1"
    func(*teste2);                 // Want "Func 2"

    return 0;
}
```

As it can be seen in the comment, what I want is that the func with an C2 argument be called when I dereference the pointer which points to a C2 class.

Edit: Just to clarify what I really want to achieve, the following code is closer to what I want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class C1 {};

class C2 : public C1 {};

void func(C1 var) {
    std::cout << "Func 1" << std::endl;
}

void func(C2 var) {
    std::cout << "Func 2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::list<C1*> teste;

    teste.push_back(new C1);
    teste.push_back(new C2);

    // Want to print:
    // Func 1
    // Func 2
    for(auto i: teste) {
        func(*i);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a wonderful first question. Welcome to StackOverflow! I hope to see more of your questions like this one!!

Comment: You mind find something useful here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/constraints C++20 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast to a `C2` pointer first if you know you're dealing with a C2 object:

```
func(*teste1);                   // Want "Func 1"
func(*static_cast<C2*>(teste2)); // Want "Func 2"
```

Alternatively, you can make `C2` polymorphic by having a virtual function in `C1`:

```
class C1 {
public:
    virtual ~C1() {}
};
```

And then you can do a [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
func(*dynamic_cast<C2*>(teste2)); // Want "Func 2"
```

Note that if you're not sure which kind of object you have, `dynamic_cast` will return a null pointer if it fails, so you can do:

```
if(dynamic_cast<C2*>(teste2)) {
    func(*dynamic_cast<C2*>(teste2)); //If it's a C2, call the C2 overload
} else {
    func(*teste2); //If it's a C1, call the C1 overload
}
```

Or even better, don't use pointers at all if you can avoid it!!

Comment: Or have `teste2` of proper type from the very beginning.

Comment: @SergeyA good point, added that on the end (I have a feeling this is part of something more complicated where pointers are necessary though).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason I want to do it is because I have a list of pointers to the class C1. I want to be able to execute func inside a for and have the right function chosen. The reasons I wanted to use pointers is because this way I can add another class (I already have 3 classes like C2) if necessary in the future and just change one or two pieces of the code. If this isn't possible, I won't use the pointers and have a list for each one of the classes.

Comment: @Gusgo99 see my edit. You can use `dynamic_cast` to tell what it's actually pointing to and call different things depending.

Comment: @scohe001 Thank you, that was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, you can make func() a virtual member function in the base, and then override it. Then a call to YourObject.func() would return what you want it to.

Virtual functions have the overhead of a vtable lookup, which can kill performance in some cases, but if it is known at compile time which type something actually is, you can use CRTP to do "static polymorphism". There are many articles about this and I recommend you learn templates first if you go this route - and definitely understand regular virtual functions first.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

class C1 {
public:
    virtual void func(){
        std::cout << "Func 1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class C2 : public C1{
public:
    void func() override{
        std::cout << "Func 2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C1* teste1 = new C1;
    C1* teste2 = new C2;

    teste1->func();                 // Want "Func 1"
    teste2->func();                 // Want "Func 2"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is that func is a member function of another class, and I didn't want C1 and C2 to have access to some member variables from this third class.